# EclipseLink-4002, ORA-02089 Error When Configuring spring jta with eclipselink jpa

Tags: spring, oracle, eclipselink, weblogic12c, jta

I'm trying to configure spring jta transactions with eclipselink jpa implementation on a sample project. I have two persistenceUnits, and I try to persist into both of these units in a method annotated with spring's @Transactional.
I'm using Weblogic and Oracle database.
Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA" name="unitOne">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>dataSourceOne</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.bionic.domain.Merchant</class>
        <class>com.bionic.domain.Payment</class>
        <class>com.bionic.domain.Customer</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle11"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.wls.WebLogicPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA" name="unitTwo">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>dataSourceTwo</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.bionic.domain.test</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle11"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.wls.WebLogicPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my app-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <description>Example configuration to get you started.</description>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bionic"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:load-time-weaver weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.weblogic.WebLogicLoadTimeWeaver" />

    <bean id="firstEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bionic"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unitOne"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="secondEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unitTwo"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

But when I try to save two entities which are reside in two different persistenceUnits like below:

```
@Transactional
public void save(Merchant m) throws Exception {
    merchantDAO.save(m);
    testService.save(createCustomer());
}
```

I get this error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2017-08-11 16:58:27.64--ServerSession(1425074737)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session
```

But surprisingly data will be persisted successfully!
What is this warning for? What should I do?

**Edit:**
Here is my complete console log:

```
[EL Info]: 2017-08-11 19:41:37.839--ServerSession(1262035974)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: 2017-08-11 19:41:37.84--ServerSession(1262035974)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Server: 12.1.3.0.0
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:37.842--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(875889108)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>OraclePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:37.904--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(273490873)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.235.97:1521:ICAS
    User: SYSTEM
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 12.1.0.2.0
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:37.904--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(946097931)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>OraclePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:37.904--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(1099003929)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.235.97:1521:ICAS
    User: SYSTEM
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 12.1.0.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-08-11 19:41:37.937--ServerSession(1262035974)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--file:/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/cluster_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/spring_war_4.0.0/5jt8t3/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_icas login successful
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.108--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(1478336679)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.121--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(1804187552)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.126--ServerSession(1262035974)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
[EL Warning]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.133--ServerSession(1262035974)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session

Error Code: 2089
Call: ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1")
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.169--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(596668732)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
[EL Info]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.178--ServerSession(1077831434)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.178--ServerSession(1077831434)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Server: 12.1.3.0.0
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.178--ServerSession(1077831434)--Connection(17386277)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>OraclePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.18--ServerSession(1077831434)--Connection(27915496)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.235.97:1521:ICASIDM
    User: SYSTEM
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 12.1.0.2.0
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.18--ServerSession(1077831434)--Connection(1024306226)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>OraclePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.18--ServerSession(1077831434)--Connection(1285826030)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.235.97:1521:ICASIDM
    User: SYSTEM
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 12.1.0.2.0
[EL Info]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.181--ServerSession(1077831434)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--file:/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/cluster_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/spring_war_4.0.0/5jt8t3/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_idm login successful
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.183--ServerSession(1077831434)--Connection(1713401159)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.185--ServerSession(1077831434)--Connection(1525056690)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.187--ServerSession(1077831434)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
[EL Warning]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.189--ServerSession(1077831434)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session

Error Code: 2089
Call: ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1")
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.19--ServerSession(1077831434)--Connection(960622064)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.198--ClientSession(667376205)--Connection(284789154)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--INSERT INTO MERCHANT (ID, ACCOUNT, BANKNAME, CHARGE, MINSUM, NAME, PERIOD, SWIFT, TOTAL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [97, 1111, 00000, 1.0, 1.0, 000000, 1, 111, 0.0]
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.205--ClientSession(1166913848)--Connection(1500378932)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--INSERT INTO TEST (ID, ADDRESS, CCNO, CCTYPE, EMAIL, MATURITY, NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [78, fd, dffd, dfdf, df@y.com, 3917-03-11, d]
[EL Fine]: 2017-08-11 19:41:38.375--ServerSession(1262035974)--Connection(1495847461)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT ID, ACCOUNT, BANKNAME, CHARGE, MINSUM, NAME, PERIOD, SWIFT, TOTAL FROM MERCHANT
```

Comment: Logging might show you what EclipseLink was doing before and when it encountered that error.

Comment: I've added the complete console log @Chris . Did you mean that? Can you figure out the reason out of that?